# monitor read/write to mtd (ubi) in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I looking for a way to monitor reads and writes to flash memory on an embedded board running buildroot.

problem is that `cat /proc/diskstats` only shows zeros in all columns (all the mtdblocks are there)

where else can I get that info? is there a missing package I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

The topic of UBI statistics has been discussed recently on the linux-mtd mailing list, and a patch has been proposed: https://lore.kernel.org/linux-mtd/1886978.5HXsB66B85@blindfold/T/.